# Do you need a .conf file in /etc/apache2 folder to run your website?

Tags: server, apache2, configuration, webserver

I am still trying to make it work, there are different tutorials for the same setup.
this tutorial says that you have to create a config file. [apache2 web server](http://funwithlinux.net/2012/05/ubuntu-12-04-web-server/)

But normally you don't need that i guess, because  you already have that in your /etc/apache2/sites-available   configuration.

So what does it change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to stick to the official documentation when possible. The tutorial you mention should work but it's far from the best practise. You shouldn't be stuffing site configuration into the `conf.d` area.

Here's our documentation for managing virtualhosts. It tells you where the configuration should go (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/`) and how you should enable it (`a2ensite`). That should explain how it's all supposed to work.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Virtual_Hosts

The rest of that document is pretty handy too.

---

And in direct answer to your direct question (if that isn't answered by the above), **yes and no**. By default Apache has a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` config file (don't get hung up on the presense or lack of extension - they're all just text files) which will serve any domain (or IP) on port 80 out of `/var/www/`.

If you want specific domain handling, like multiple virtual hosts, you're going to want to add another site configuration file.

Comment: ok. thank you, can i easily add to ports.conf  some ports like 81 and 82 to the listening ports. and change port from 80 to something else for my second website? thanks in advance

Comment: @Private To my knowledge, that's also handled in the virtual host configuration. `<VirtualHost domain.ext:80>` (you'd change the 80)